# Play Framework: get object from YAML file by identifier

Tags: playframework, yaml, playframework-1.x

I have data stored in a .yml file. Example:

```
User(bob):
  email: bob@gmail.com
  password: secret
  username: Bobby
  country: US
  status: ACTIVE
```

I would like to get this object in tests (by identifier "bob"). Is that possible at all? Could not find the answer in documentation.

*Play framework 1.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, this identifier is only used to reference the object in the yaml file but does not match any attribute of the object

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the open source YamlBeans library, it's good at this kind of thing.